# Thermal resistance of anodized aluminium interface

Tags: heatsink

I'm considering [extruded aluminium enclosures](https://www.hammfg.com/electronics/small-case/extruded/1455) for a power amplifier, but need to do something with as much as 255W of heat. Currently I have a sufficient heat sink, attached directly to the transistors. If I attached the transistors to the anodized aluminium enclosure, and the heat sink to that (all with appropriate thermal grease, of course), what thermal performance can I expect? Can I estimate the additional thermal resistance due to the interface between the parts?

Comment: Here's some papers about it, the first one lists some thermal conductivity for various anodized coatings https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4c7e/a50b08f9403881dfd831f819da36e3418524.pdf   This one's not free http://heattransfer.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/article.aspx?articleid=1440455

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy That last one is free from SciHub: [Measurement of the Thermal Contact Conductance and Thermal Conductivity of Anodized Aluminum Coatings](https://sci-hub.la/10.1115/1.2910426).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coating (on both sides) has a thickness of about 50um or less (according e.g. to [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4c7e/a50b08f9403881dfd831f819da36e3418524.pdf)) and a thermal conductivity of 0.5 ... 1.5 W/Km (let's use 1.0 W/Km in the simple calculation below).

The extruded aluminium housing has a thickness of 1.5mm and a thermal conductivity of up to 200 W/Km.

The thermal grease layer has a more or less undefined thickness (also changing over time) in the range of 50 - 100um. As a rule of thumb designers often set the layer thickness to 100um and its thermal conductivity to 1 W/Km.

This gives a thermal resistance power module "case to sink" of

$$
\begin{align}
R_{th} &=
{2 \cdot \num{50e-6} \over A}
 + {\num{1.5e-3} \over 200 \cdot A}
 + {2 \cdot \num{100e-6} \over A}
\\
&= {\num{100e-6} + \num{7.5e-6} + \num{200e-6} \over A} \\
&= {\num{0.3e-3} \over A}
\end{align}$$

with \$A\$ being the semiconductor module case size (footprint) in square-meters.

Without the housing (power module directly on heatsink) your actual thermal resistance is about 3 times smaller:

$$ R_{th} = {\num{100e-6} \over A} = {\num{0.1e-3} \over A} $$

Comment: According to what papers?

Comment: The link in the comment directly below the question.